# Android 13 "Does your app use Advertising ID -> Only for analytics", the App will be marked like "Contains ads"?

Tags: android

> **New Advertising ID declaration form coming to Console**
>
> Starting July, you'll need to tell us in Play Console if your app uses an advertising identifier. This will let us provide helpful feedback if your release is at risk of having an advertising identifier zeroed out. You will not be able to create releases targeting Android 13 until you complete the advertising ID declaration form.

My app don't contain any ads, but advertising ID is used in third party analytics libraries.
So, if i choose "Does your app use Advertising ID -> only for Analytics" my app in play market will be marked like "Contains ads"? [I wanna avoid that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJwJv.png).
I don't want to remove AD_ID from manifest - it can do analytics data incorrect.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en

Can someone who chooses this "only Analytics" option share experience, your app got a ads mark?

Comment: Same situation here. In case what @youssef-wagih is saying in the first answer is correct, are you aware of any other downsides for declaring that the app uses Advertising ID?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be marked as **contains ads** in play store while showing app for users.

**Advertiding ID** is used by analytics tools (third parties) for example by facebook analytics for their ads in facebook platform so they your are not displaying ads in the app itself.